# Generate regular polygon in Javascript with base side always at the bottom

Tags: javascript, svg, polygon

Is here a way how to generate regular polygon with `X` sides, but the base (first) side should be always horizontal at the bottom. I've found any of generators, e.g. https://codepen.io/winkerVSbecks/pen/wrZQQm, but it does not generate the base side at the bottom and more, it has some "wierd" padding inside the viewbox I could not get rid of (the polygon does not use the full width and height of svg viewbox, but it has spaces at edges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varun Vachhar's [codepen "SVG Polygon Generator"](https://codepen.io/winkerVSbecks/pen/wrZQQm)
already includes a parameter to adjust the starting angle.
Change the `offsetDeg` (in `pts(sideCount, radius)`) value like so:

`let offsetDeg = (180 - angle) / 2;`

The generator calculates polygon vertices according to the current radius value. So all vertices will be on a circle. But the `viewBox` won't automatically adjust width and height according to the rendered polygon.

To achieve a cropped polygon svg you can either:

- recalculate the `viewBox` via [`getBBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) after rendering the polygon
- or recalculate the polygon coordinates by finding x and y extrema to find appropriate offsets

#### Example 1: crop via viewBox adjustment

```js
const sideCountEl = document.querySelector('#js-side-count');
const radiusEl = document.querySelector('#js-radius');
const cxEl = document.querySelector('#js-cx');
const cyEl = document.querySelector('#js-cy');
const generateEl = document.querySelector('#js-generate');
const polygonEl = document.querySelector('#js-polygon');
const resultEl = document.querySelector('#js-result');
const svgEl = document.querySelector('#jsSvg');

function pts(sideCount, radius) {
  const angle = 360 / sideCount;
  const vertexIndices = range(sideCount);
  let offsetDeg = (180 - angle) / 2;
  const offset = degreesToRadians(offsetDeg);

  return vertexIndices.map(index => {
    return {
      theta: offset + degreesToRadians(angle * index),
      r: radius
    };

  });
}

function range(count) {
  return Array.from(Array(count).keys());
}

function degreesToRadians(angleInDegrees) {
  return Math.PI * angleInDegrees / 180;
}


function polygon([cx, cy], sideCount, radius) {
  return pts(sideCount, radius).
  map(({
    r,
    theta
  }) => [
    cx + r * Math.cos(theta),
    cy + r * Math.sin(theta)
  ]);

}

function generatePolygon() {
  const sideCount = +sideCountEl.value;
  const radius = +radiusEl.value;
  const s = 2 * radius;

  let polyPoints = polygon([s / 2, s / 2], sideCount, radius);
  polygonEl.setAttribute('points', polyPoints.flat().join(' '));

  // crop by - adjust viewBox to current bbox
  let bb = polygonEl.getBBox();
  svgEl.setAttribute('viewBox', `${bb.x} ${bb.y} ${bb.width} ${bb.height}`);

  // show output
  resultEl.value = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(jsSvg);

}

window.onload = generatePolygon;

// Listen to changes in <input />
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('input', e => generatePolygon());
});

// convert to relative path data
function polyPointsToPathRelative(polyPoints, precision) {
  let pointsRel = [];
  let offXrel = 0;
  let offYrel = 0;

  polyPoints.forEach(pt => {
    let [x, y] = [pt[0] - offXrel, pt[1] - offYrel];
    pointsRel.push(x, y)
    offXrel += x;
    offYrel += y;
  });

  // round
  pointsRel = pointsRel.map(val => {
    return +val.toFixed(precision)
  });
  let M = pointsRel.splice(0, 2);
  let pathData = 'M' + M.join(' ') + 'l' + pointsRel.join(' ') + 'z';

  return pathData;

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.15;
  margin: 0;
}

body,
div,
fieldset,
form,
input[type=number],
legend,
main,
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ba {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.bb {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.b--dark-gray {
  border-color: #333;
}

.b--transparent {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.bw2 {
  border-width: .25rem;
}

.db {
  display: block;
}

.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.min-vh-100 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.tracked {
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}

.mw7 {
  max-width: 48rem;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.pa0 {
  padding: 0;
}

.pa2 {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.pa3 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.pa4 {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.pv2 {
  padding-top: .5rem;
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
}

.ph0 {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.mb0 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mb2 {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.mb4 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.mt5 {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.mv4 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.mh0 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.ttu {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.f5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.measure-wide {
  max-width: 34em;
}

.center {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.flex-row-ns {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.mr4-ns {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.mb0-ns {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

legend,
label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

pre {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20em;
  white-space: pre-wrap !important;
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

```html
<main class="pa4 dark-gray mw7 center sans-serif min-vh-100 flex flex-column flex-row-ns ">
  <form class="measure-wide mr4-ns mb4 mb0-ns f5">
    <fieldset class="ba b--transparent pa0 mh0">

      <legend class="f5 b ph0 mh0 ttu tracked bb bw2 pv2 db w-100">
        Polygon Generator
      </legend>

      <div class="mt5 mb4">
        <label class="f5 ttu tracked db b mb2" for="js-side-count">
          Number of Sides
        </label>
        <input class="b pa2 input-reset ba bw2 bg-white b--dark-gray w-100" type="number" id="js-side-count" min="3" value="8">
      </div>
      <div class="mv4">
        <label class="f5 ttu tracked db b mb2" for="js-radius">
          Radius
        </label>
        <input class="b pa2 input-reset ba bw2 bg-white b--dark-gray w-100" type="number" id="js-radius" value="200">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div class="flex-auto flex items-center justify-center w-100">
    <div class="w-100">
      <svg class="w-100 white debug-grid mb4 db" viewBox="0 0 800 800" stroke="#111" fill="none" stroke-width="4" id="jsSvg">
        <polygon id="js-polygon" points="" />
      </svg>
      <textarea id="js-result" class="code pa3 bg-near-white mb0 overflow-scroll"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

#### Example 2: crop by recalculating polygon coordinates

```js
const sideCountEl = document.querySelector('#js-side-count');
const radiusEl = document.querySelector('#js-radius');
const generateEl = document.querySelector('#js-generate');
const polygonEl = document.querySelector('#js-polygon');
const resultEl = document.querySelector('#js-result');
const svgEl = document.querySelector('#jsSvg');

function pts(sideCount, radius) {
  const angle = 360 / sideCount;
  const vertexIndices = range(sideCount);
  let offsetDeg = (180 - angle) / 2;
  const offset = degreesToRadians(offsetDeg);

  return vertexIndices.map(index => {
    return {
      theta: offset + degreesToRadians(angle * index),
      r: radius
    };

  });
}

function range(count) {
  return Array.from(Array(count).keys());
}

function degreesToRadians(angleInDegrees) {
  return Math.PI * angleInDegrees / 180;
}


function polygon([cx, cy], sideCount, radius) {
  return pts(sideCount, radius).
  map(({
    r,
    theta
  }) => [
    cx + r * Math.cos(theta),
    cy + r * Math.sin(theta)
  ]);

}

function generatePolygon() {
  const sideCount = +sideCountEl.value;
  const radius = +radiusEl.value;
  const s = 2 * radius;

  // calculate polygont points
  let polyPoints = polygon([s / 2, s / 2], sideCount, radius);

  /**
   * find x and y extrema
   * to crop and pan polygon and viewBox
   */
  let xVals = polyPoints.map(pt => {
    return pt[0]
  });
  let yVals = polyPoints.map(pt => {
    return pt[1]
  });

  let left = Math.min(...xVals);
  let right = Math.max(...xVals);
  let top = Math.min(...yVals);
  let bottom = Math.max(...yVals);
  let width = right - left;
  let height = bottom - top;

  // round coordinates
  let precision = +inputPrecision.value;

  // calculate cropped polygon
  polyPoints = polyPoints.map(pt => {
    return [+(pt[0] - left).toFixed(precision), +(pt[1] - top).toFixed(precision)];
  });

  // create relative path
  let pathData = polyPointsToPathRelative(polyPoints, precision)


  // shift points - adjust viewBox
  svgEl.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${+width.toFixed(precision)} ${+height.toFixed(precision)}`);
  polygonEl.setAttribute('d', pathData);

  let output = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(jsSvg).
  replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").
  replaceAll('> <', '><').
  replaceAll('<', '\n<');

  //console.log(output);
  resultEl.value = output;

}

window.onload = generatePolygon;

// Listen to changes in <input />
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('input', e => generatePolygon());
});

// convert to relative path data
function polyPointsToPathRelative(polyPoints, precision) {
  let pointsRel = [];
  let offXrel = 0;
  let offYrel = 0;

  polyPoints.forEach(pt => {
    let [x, y] = [pt[0] - offXrel, pt[1] - offYrel];
    pointsRel.push(x, y)
    offXrel += x;
    offYrel += y;
  });

  // round
  pointsRel = pointsRel.map(val => {
    return +val.toFixed(precision)
  });
  let M = pointsRel.splice(0, 2);
  let pathData = 'M' + M.join(' ') + 'l' + pointsRel.join(' ') + 'z';

  return pathData;

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.15;
  margin: 0;
}

body,
div,
fieldset,
form,
input[type=number],
legend,
main,
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ba {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.bb {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.b--dark-gray {
  border-color: #333;
}

.b--transparent {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.bw2 {
  border-width: .25rem;
}

.db {
  display: block;
}

.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.min-vh-100 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.tracked {
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}

.mw7 {
  max-width: 48rem;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.pa0 {
  padding: 0;
}

.pa2 {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.pa3 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.pa4 {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.pv2 {
  padding-top: .5rem;
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
}

.ph0 {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.mb0 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mb2 {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.mb4 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.mt5 {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.mv4 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.mh0 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.ttu {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.f5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.measure-wide {
  max-width: 34em;
}

.center {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.flex-row-ns {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.mr4-ns {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.mb0-ns {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

legend,
label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

pre {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20em;
  white-space: pre-wrap !important;
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

```html
<main class="pa4 dark-gray mw7 center sans-serif min-vh-100 flex flex-column flex-row-ns ">
  <form class="measure-wide mr4-ns mb4 mb0-ns f5">
    <fieldset class="ba b--transparent pa0 mh0">
      <legend class="f5 b ph0 mh0 ttu tracked bb bw2 pv2 db w-100">
        Polygon Generator
      </legend>
      <div class="mt5 mb4">
        <label class="f5 ttu tracked db b mb2" for="js-side-count">
          Number of Sides
        </label>
        <input class="b pa2 input-reset ba bw2 bg-white b--dark-gray w-100" type="number" id="js-side-count" min="3" value="8">
      </div>
      <div class="mv4">
        <label class="f5 ttu tracked db b mb2" for="js-radius">
          Radius
        </label>
        <input class="b pa2 input-reset ba bw2 bg-white b--dark-gray w-100" type="number" id="js-radius" value="200">
      </div>
      <div class="mv4">
        <label class="f5 ttu tracked db b mb2" for="js-radius">
          precision
        </label>
        <input class="b pa2 input-reset ba bw2 bg-white b--dark-gray w-100" type="number" id="inputPrecision" value="2">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div class="flex-auto flex items-center justify-center w-100">
    <div class="w-100">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 800 800" id="jsSvg">
        <path id="js-polygon" d="" />
      </svg>

      <textarea id="js-result" class="code pa3 bg-near-white mb0 overflow-scroll"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

The above example also converts polygon points to a path data string.

Usually, svg `<path>` elements offer a more concise notation – as they also support relative commands and can also be combined as compound paths.

You can easily convert a `<polygon>` element to a `<path>` equivalent by simply prepending a "M" and appending a "z" command letter to the `points` attribute.

```
<polygon points="244.949 386.37 141.421 386.37 51.764 334.607 0 244.949 0 141.421 51.764 51.764 141.421 0 244.949 0 334.607 51.764 386.37 141.421 386.37 244.949 334.607 334.607"/>
```

equals

```
<path d="M 244.949 386.37 141.421 386.37 51.764 334.607 0 244.949 0 141.421 51.764 51.764 141.421 0 244.949 0 334.607 51.764 386.37 141.421 386.37 244.949 334.607 334.607 z"/>
```

The offset values are calculated by looping through the point array like this:

```
  /**
   * find x and y extrema
   * to crop and pan polygon and viewBox
   */
  let xVals = polyPoints.map(pt => {
    return pt[0]
  });
  let yVals = polyPoints.map(pt => {
    return pt[1]
  });

  let left = Math.min(...xVals);
  let right = Math.max(...xVals);
  let top = Math.min(...yVals);
  let bottom = Math.max(...yVals);
  let width = right - left;
  let height = bottom - top;

  // round coordinates
  let precision = +inputPrecision.value;

  // calculate cropped polygon
  polyPoints = polyPoints.map(pt => {
    return [+(pt[0] - left).toFixed(precision), +(pt[1] - top).toFixed(precision)];
  });
    

  // shift points - adjust viewBox
  svgEl.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${+width.toFixed(precision)} ${+height.toFixed(precision)}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code, the polygon generator seems to be generating the "flat" side on the right edge. So it is just a matter of rotating all angles by 90deg clockwise (aka `0.5 * Math.PI` radians) when drawing the polygon:

```
function polygon([cx, cy], sideCount, radius) {
  return pts(sideCount, radius)
    .map(({ r, theta }) => {
      // NOTE: Update theta to add 90deg clockwise rotation
      return [
        cx + r * Math.cos(theta + Math.PI * 0.5),
        cy + r * Math.sin(theta + Math.PI * 0.5)
      ];
    })
    .join(" ");
}
```

See forked CodePen here: https://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/LYJQMda

Comment: Cool, it looks it work properly, thanks. Only problem is with the padding of viewbox now. Polygon should display from edge to edge when I choose radius `325`, center `325 x 325` and place generated points to svg with `viewbox="0 0 650 650"`, should it not? But still, there is couple of pixels near to all edges.

Comment: That’s an entirely different question.

Comment: And does it matter? I mentioned this issue in main topic above.

Answer (score 2):

##### You can reduce all that code to a native JavaScript Web Component (JSWC):

```html
<svg-polygon sides="8"  fill="red"></svg-polygon>
<svg-polygon sides="9"  fill="yellow"></svg-polygon>
<svg-polygon sides="10" fill="blue"></svg-polygon>
```

[image]

```js
customElements.define("svg-polygon", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    var radians = (deg) => (Math.PI * deg) / 180;
    var sides   = +this.getAttribute("sides") || 8;
    var radius  = +this.getAttribute("radius") || 200;
    var vb      = 2*radius + (this.getAttribute("padding") || 50);
    var points  = Array(sides).fill(radians(90-((180-(360/sides))/2)))
         .map((offset,idx) => [
            vb/2 + radius*Math.cos(offset+radians((360/sides)*idx) + Math.PI/2),
            vb/2 + radius*Math.sin(offset+radians((360/sides)*idx) + Math.PI/2)
         ]);
    this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 ${vb} ${vb}">` +
      `<polygon points="${points.join(" ")}" fill="${this.getAttribute("fill")}"/>` +
      `</svg>`;
  }
})
```

```css
svg { width:180px; background:pink }
```

```html
<svg-polygon sides="8" fill="red"></svg-polygon>
<svg-polygon sides="9" fill="yellow"></svg-polygon>
<svg-polygon sides="10" fill="blue"></svg-polygon>
```